# How long can this sequence be?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

The positive integers $a,b$ with $a>1$ and the prime $n$ is given.

Define the sequence $u$ with the recurrence relation : $u_1=n$ , $u_{j+1}=a\cdot u_j+b$ for all $j\ge 1$. The sequence terminates as soon as the next term is composite.

For example , with $n=587, a=3,b=16$ , the sequence has length $11$ because $u_{12}$ is composite.

> Can this sequence be arbitary long ? If no, what is the maximal possible length ?

Comment: It is believed that $a=2$, $b=1$ leads to arbitrarily long sequences of primes, but no one has been able to prove it. Probably the same is true for any values with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a,b$ not both odd.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain

Comment: Any thoughts on the matter, Peter?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your insight, $12$ primes is already a difficult task as practical culations show.